# Como tirar todos os consoles.logs, erros e alertas do console para o cleinte (devtools)

Tags: react, aplicação-web, console, next.js, dev-tools

Tenho uma aplicação next.JS e preciso que ela seja bem indexada. Estou fazendo algumas alterações e melhorias seguindo o lighthouse. Porem apareceu um erro de "boas praticas" que eu sempre tive duvidas.

Como tirar tudo que tem no console para o cliente? Como fazer todos os erros, alertas, consoles logs etc não aparecerem mais para o cliente caso ele de F12.

Acredito que seja possivel, pois sites grandes como facebook não tem nada no console, e sabemos que dificilmente um site não terá consoles, erros e alertas, ainda mais com o tamanho e complexidade do facebook. Sites do google mesmo não tem nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Opa, existem libs que podem lhe auxiliar com isso, mas você também pode criar um wrapper do console.log para lhe auxiliar, a ideia é verificar o ambiente que está sendo executado e executar ou não o console.log.

Um pequeno exemplo.

```
const log = { info: (msg) => { if(ENV==="PROD") return; console.log(msg)  } }
```

Aqui a variavel ENV é uma variavel de ambiente que informa o ambiente em que está sendo executado (produção, desenvolvimento, stage, local), caso seja produção nada é executado.

[obs] Verifique o que pode ser impactado ao não executar o console.log.

Utilização:

```
log.info("Executando operação XYZ");
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito interessante amigo, vou tentar fazer desta maneira. Quais libs que fazem isso ? Você conhece alguma?.

Comment: E esse wrapper ficaria onde? Seria so um componente criado para ficar em volta do site inteiro? ou seria colocado no public do site por script JS